# Change syntax highlighting without changing major mode?

Tags: shell, syntax-highlighting, repl

I want to start a python-shell `M-x python-shell`. If I'm not happy with the syntax highlighting, is it possible to improve it (put more colors in the buffer) without changing major mode? In vim this would be simple with `set filetype=python`.

**The python syntax itself is not highlighted in python-shell mode, I want it to be highlighted.**

A simple solution will be favored because I'm just learning about emacs.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What "highlighter"? If you are asking whether you can change `font-lock-keywords` for a given mode, then yes. But depending on how the mode function is defined, re-entering the mode might re-highlight using the mode-defined `font-lock-keywords` and not what you have redefined. To be safer in that (but with no guarantee), you would need to redefine `font-lock-keywords` on the mode hook, so that it takes effect each time the mode is turned on, and after the mode code does its thing.

Comment: Clarifying: do you want to turn *off* syntax highlighting, do you dislike the default color ("face") choices and want to change them, or do you want to add new highlighting on top of the existing highlighting?  As @Drew suggested, it's going to involve `font-lock-keywords` in some way, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @Drew I meant the syntax highlighter. @ Dan the current python-shell mode (in emacs23) doesn't color python syntax so I want to add color.

Comment: @Malabarba should be fixed now.

Comment: @Joelmob Great, looks much clearer now.

Comment: *Syntax highlighting* generally means `font-lock-keywords`. See what I wrote about changing that in connection with a major mode.

Comment: Cant you switch to a newer `python.el`? IIRC, the one shipped since emacs 24.2 had font lock for the shell as well.

Answer (score 4):

Every major mode that supports font-lock does so via `font-lock-defaults`. If you check `python-mode`, you'll see the following:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
     '(python-font-lock-keywords nil nil nil nil))
```

If you're in a different major mode, you should be able to set `font-lock-defaults` to `(python-font-lock-keywords nil nil nil nil)` either interactively using `M-:` or via a hook.