# How to customize syntax highlight for just a given mode

Tags: customize, faces, font-lock

I would like to change the syntax highlighting in my `lua-mode.el` without affecting other major modes.

Just as an example, I would like "key words" like `if`, `then`, `else` to be in bold and blue typeface when in `lua-mode` (instead of the default pink) without having the same highlighting style while editing a `.tex` file with AUCTeX.

So far I have tried to put the following code in my `.emacs` and then also in my `lua-mode.el`:

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground "maroon3"))))
  '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "green4"))))
  '(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "dark blue" :weight bold))))
  '(font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "dark cyan")))))
```

but this way I get the same syntax highlighting for every mode I work with.

This question might be related: [Change syntax highlighting without changing major mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/change-syntax-highlighting-without-changing-major-mode)

Is there a (hopefully simple and general) way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Faces are global so changing its attributes anywhere changes it
everywhere, as you've noticed.  To change it locally, make a copy of
the face, change the attributes in the copy and then use a mode hook
to locally set the old face to the copy on a per-buffer basis.  The
sample below does it for `font-lock-comment-face`, but the same
incantation will work for any face.

```
(make-variable-buffer-local 'font-lock-comment-face)
(copy-face 'font-lock-comment-face 'lua-comment-face)
(set-face-foreground 'lua-comment-face "green4")

(add-hook 'lua-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq font-lock-comment-face 'lua-comment-face)            
            ))
```