# How would you customize a subsection of keywords in a major mode in Emacs?

Tags: font-lock

Is it possible to customize some, not all, of keywords in a major mode?
(Pardon my vocabulary, since this is still new to me.)

For example, let's say these are keywords: `function`, `new`, `throw`, `return`.
And I want to override the look of `throw` and `new`, but leave `function` and `return` alone.

Comment: probably. see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/how-to-customize-syntax-highlight-for-just-a-given-mode and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords. Also, this question isn't spacemacs-specific

Comment: I don't think the question is a duplicate if it's about **some** keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to customize some keywords of a mode. For example, here is a way to highlight `throw` and `new` in bold yellow, in Java mode:

```el
;; define the look for your modified keywords
(defface my-keyword-face
  '((default :foreground "yellow" :weight bold))
  "Face for my own keywords.")

;; define the keywords you want to modify
(defvar my-modified-java-keywords
  '(("\\<\\(throw\\)\\>" . 'my-keyword-face)
    ("\\<\\(new\\)\\>" . 'my-keyword-face)))

;; modify the keywords
(font-lock-add-keywords 'java-mode my-modified-java-keywords)
```

More detailed information is found in [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords), [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Mode.html) and the documentation for the relevant functions in Emacs.